# Group rows by Year Band Interval

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table (tbl_people), in this table I have a datetime field I want to group and count the records in groups of 10 years... The result should be something like:
    |   count    | year           |
    |  1000      |  1980-1989  |
    | 250       |  1990-1999  |

I can write multiple queries to do it, but that means I'll have to write different queries for each range. Is there a way to dynamically increment from the least year upwards (10 year intervals) and count the number of records within the intervals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First calculate the decade for each row

```
select floor(year(`year`) / 10) * 10 as decade
from tbl_people
```

and then use this intermediate result for counting [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee2b3/3/0)

```
select count(*), decade, decade + 9
from (select floor(year(`year`) / 10) * 10 as decade
      from tbl_people) t
group by decade
```

or this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee2b3/5/1), if you want the decade in one column

```
select count(*) as count, concat(decade, '-', decade + 9) as year
from (select floor(year(`year`) / 10) * 10 as decade
      from tbl_people) t
group by decade
```

Answer (score 1):

This will helps .

```
 select CONCAT(FLOOR(YEAR(from_unixtime(TIMESTAMP))/10)*10,'-',(FLOOR(YEAR(from_unixtime(TIMESTAMP))/10)*10)+9) as year , count(ID) from 
    TABLE group by FLOOR(YEAR(from_unixtime(TIMESTAMP))/10)*10;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work - [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee2b3/10) (thanks to Olaf Dietsche for showing me that this wonderful site exists):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(`year`) as `count`,
    CONCAT(
        FLOOR(YEAR(`year`) / 10) * 10, 
        '-', 
        (CEIL(YEAR(`year`) / 10) * 10) - 1
    ) as `year`
FROM
    `tbl_people`
GROUP BY
    CONCAT(
        FLOOR(YEAR(`year`) / 10) * 10,
        '-', 
        (CEIL(YEAR(`year`) / 10) * 10) - 1
    )
```

If the number is 1992, `FLOOR(1992 / 10)` will give `199`, and times with `10` will give `1990`. The same thing about `CEIL(1992 / 10)` = `200` and times `10` = `2000`, minus `1`, gives `1999` so the `year` should be `1990-1999`.

Comment: I need to select the minimum year from the table. Then create bands based on that. Olaf's answer does it.