# how can I calculate the SUM in 4days buckets over all dates

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL DB where one column is the DATE and the other column is the SIGNAL. Now I would like to calculate the SUM over Signal for 4 days each.

f.e.

```
    SUM(signal over DATE1,DATE2,DATE3,DATE4)
    SUM(signal over DATE5,DATE6,DATE7,DATE8)
    ...

    whereas Date_N =  successor of DATE_N-1 but need not to be the day before
```

Moreless the algo should be variable in the days group. 4 ist just an example.

Can anyone here give me an advice how to perform this in MySQL?

I have found this here [group by with count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857538/mysql-count-group-by-having), maybe this could be helpful for my issue?
Thanks

Edit: One important note: My date ranges have gaps in it. you see this in the picture below, in the column count(DISTINCT(TradeDate)). It should be always 4 when I have no gaps. But I DO have gaps. But when I sort the date descending, I would like to group the dates together always 4 days, f.e. Group1: 2017-08-22 + 2017-08-21 + 2017-08-20 + 2017-08-19, Group2: 2017-08-18 + 2017-08-17+2017-08-15+2017-08-14, ...

maybe I could map the decending dateranges into a decending integer autoincrement number, then I would have a number without gaps. number[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857538/mysql-count-group-by-having)="2017-08-17" number[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZv8f.png)="2017-08-15" and so on ..

Edit2:
As I see the result from my table with this Query: I might I have double entries for one and the same date. How Can I distinct this date-doubles into only one reprensentative?

```
     SELECT SUM(CondN1),count(id),count(DISTINCT(TradeDate)),min(TradeDate),max(TradeDate)  ,min(TO_DAYS(DATE(TradeDate))),id FROM marketstat where Stockplace like '%'   GROUP BY TO_DAYS(DATE(TradeDate)) DIV 4 order by TO_DAYS(DATE(TradeDate))
```

[image: Result of my Table]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13780140/747609 might guide you

Comment: Show us some data.  What is `DATE1`?

Comment: @IROEGBU THANKS! that is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen DATE1 is a DateTIME f.e. 2017-08-25 13:00:00 and DATE2 is f.e. 2017-08-22 10:00:00

Answer (score 2):

`SUM()` is a grouping function, so you need to `GROUP BY` something. That something should change only every four days. Let's start by grouping by one day:

```
SELECT SUM(signal) 
FROM tableName
GROUP BY date
```

`date` should really be of type `DATE`, like you mentioned, not `DATETIME` or anything else. You could use `DATE(date)` to convert other date types to dates. Now we need to group by four dates:

```
SELECT SUM(signal) 
FROM tableName
GROUP BY TO_DAYS(date) DIV 4
```

Note that this will create an arbitary group of four days, if you want control over that you can add a term like this:

```
SELECT SUM(signal) 
FROM tableName
GROUP BY (TO_DAYS(date)+2) DIV 4
```

Comment: One more question to your great solution: I have not all dates continously I have dateranges with leaps. maybe we can make a select where we order by id or date and take always the corresponding 4 days-dates. Can you understand what I mean.

Comment: If you just want to to group by four successive dates, you only have one row per date and your id is sequential and auto-increasing, then you can simply replace `TO_DAYS(date)` by `id` to achieve what you want. In all other cases it will get more complex. Since this is clearly different from you current question you should ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks to verify my assumption, as I did it in my answer. You was a great help

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime and with help of KIKO I have found the solution:
I make a temp table with

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE  if not EXISTS tradedatemaptmp (id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY) SELECT Tradedate AS Tradedate, CondN1, CondN2 FROM marketstat WHERE marketstat.Stockplace like 'US' GROUP BY TradeDate ORDER BY TradeDate asc;
```

and use instead the originate tradedate the now created id in the temp table. So I could manage that - even when I have gaps in the tradedate range, the id in the tmp table has no gaps. And with this I can DIV 4 and get the always the corresponding 4 dates together.[image]